# How to excute multiple commands in multiple shells Python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

The issue is that i need to access multiple shells within the same process, since i have a sytem that can conect to multiple nodes i might need to execute a command on a the system and then on the node and i need to send multiple commands on the node without creating another process

i wrote this code for example to access Sybase db on my solaris system (for some reason i couldn't install the Sybase module on the version we have of Python 2.6)

```
cmd1 = 'isql -Usa -w1024 -P********'
cmd2 = 'use imhdb'
cmd3 = 'go'
cmd4 = "SELECT Id_number, Object_name FROM IM_top WHERE Object_name LIKE'%BtsSiteMgr=CAI3533%'"

final = Popen("{0}; {1}; {2}; {3}".format(cmd1, cmd2, cmd3,cmd4),shell=True,stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, close_fds=True)
stdout, nothing = final.communicate()
print(stdout)
```

The Output : 
    /bin/sh: use: not found
    /bin/sh: go: not found
    /bin/sh: SELECT: not found

That's because after it's has executed the first command it creates another process as bash not in the sybase sql console so commands o fcourse aren't recognized.so how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAICS that `isql` is a command which opens an interactive console, and then the subsequent commands (`use imhdb`, `go`, `SELECT`) are commands to be entered *in* that console.

Your approach will create a separate process for each command and thus fail.

You should instead create a subprocess only for the first command and then pipe your three SQL-related commands *into* the existing subprocess:

```
sqlProcess = Popen(cmd1, shell='True', stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
print >>sqlProcess.stdin, cmd2
print >>sqlProcess.stdin, cmd3
print >>sqlProcess.stdin, cmd4
sqlProcess.stdin.close()  # signal end of input
```

Then you can fetch the results from the stdout of that subprocess:

```
print sqlProcess.stdout.read()
```